# Compare a column with multiple row to a colum with a single row

Tags: sas

I'm currently working with the SAS Studio free version and I'm just starting (about 2 weeks). I'm a former MATLAB user but SAS is way more complicated ^^.

Firstly, I created a new table where I calculated the 25th, 50th and 75th percentiles of 2 variables (MSRP and Invoice) from the library SASHELP.cars. I got a new table with a single row and 6 columns (3 percentiles for 2 variables). I named the percentiles as Invoice_P25, etc.

Here's the code if it may help you, I also put the code and what I would like to generate in the attachments:

```
proc univariate data=work.Regress noprint;
  var MSRP Invoice;
  output out=work.temp1 pctlpts=25 50 75 pctlpre=MSRP_ Invoice_
  pctlname=P25 P50 P75; /* Compute 25th, 50th and 75th quantiles */
run;
```

Here's my problem:

With these percentiles, I want to create a table where a column tells where's the MSRP of the car is, compared of the rest of MSRPs distribution. Same for the "Invoice".

I tried with a structure with a "if". But **when I compare a column (428 rows of MSRP) with a percentile, it doesn't work with its name but if I replace by its value, it works.** I think SAS assumed the percentile is a column with 428 rows too but just the first row has a value.

How can I fix that please? Here's my code:

```
data work.temp;
set work.Regress work.temp1;
/* (keep=var1 var2)
(drop=var1 var2) */
 
length QMSRP $6; /* longueur de nouvelle colonne = 6 caractÃ¨res */
if MSRP < vvalue(MSRP_P25) then QMSRP = 'QMSRP1';
else if MSRP >= vvalue(MSRP_P25) and MSRP < vvalue(MSRP_P50) then QMSRP = 'QMSRP2';
else if MSRP >= vvalue(MSRP_P50) and MSRP < vvalue(MSRP_P75) then QMSRP = 'QMSRP3';
else QMSRP = 'QMSRP4';
 
length QInvoice $9;
if Invoice < Invoice_P25 then QInvoice = 'QInvoice1';
else if Invoice >= Invoice_P25 and Invoice < Invoice_P50 then QInvoice = 'QInvoice2';
else if Invoice >= Invoice_P50 and Invoice < Invoice_P75 then QInvoice = 'QInvoice3';
else QInvoice = 'QInvoice4';
 
run;
```

PS: sorry if some words are in French in the pictures I couldn't change the language.

[SASCode + Table wanted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GX2he.png)

Comment: Are you doing this as an exercise? It's definitely not the optimal way to do this in SAS. You're better off using PROC RANK with GROUPS=4 to create the groups for you. Or Groups=10 if you want deciles. Or 100 if you want actual percentiles. I think you get the idea.

Comment: I have a macro that does it here but macros may be beyond what you know right now https://gist.github.com/statgeek/7cffd06ebc3bc9c78b4f6a5b4538b053

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code tells SAS to read the REGRESS dataset and then the TEMP1 dataset. So you would get something like

```
Obs MSRP ... P25
  1 1,000    . 
  2 5,000    .
...
N+1     .   2,250
```

But it sounds like you would like the values of P25, etc. on each observation of REGRESS.  So in that case just read the values once.  Since they are coming from a dataset they will be retained onto all of the observations in the data step.

```
data want ;
  set regress ;
  if _n_=1 then set temp1;
  ....
```

That way you will get values like this instead.

```
Obs MSRP ... P25
  1 1,000    2,250
  2 5,000    2,250
...
  N 4,000    2,250
```

Comment: Thank you very much it worked, problem solved.